# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cat' of undefined (this.dataset.cat)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dataset, element, typeerror

**Solution:** <SVG> does not support the data-* attribute. You can define your own attributes and call them with getAttribute. In my case, `this.dataset.cat` becomes `this.getAttribute("cat")` and `&lt;svg data-cat="1">` becomes `&lt;svg cat="1">`

---

I have this basic image viewer on a web page and it worked when I put it up a couple months ago but now for some reason I went and tried to use it and it's now throwing errors. Not sure what I did to this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arrows = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow");
  for (var i = 0; i < arrows.length; i++) {
    arrows[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      $(".slide").finish(); //Instantly finishes slide animation
      if (this.className.baseVal == "arrow right") {
        scrollNext(this.dataset.cat); //ERROR
      } else {
        scrollPrevious(this.dataset.cat); //ERROR
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<svg id="c1Left" class="arrow left" data-cat="1">
  <polygon points="0,50 50,0 50,15 15,50 50,85 50,100">
</svg>
<img id="c1Previous" class="slide previous" />
<img id="c1Current" class="slide current" src="folder/subfolder/0.png" />
<img id="c1Next" class="slide next" src="folder/subfolder/1.png" />
<svg id="c1Right" class="arrow right" data-cat="1">
  <polygon points="50,50 0,0 0,15 35,50 0,85 0,100">
</svg>
```

The lines commented ERROR throw:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cat' of undefined

This would lead me to believe that it's trying to define the click events and assign dataset.id before the elements are loaded but that shouldn't happen because it should only be initialized after the document is fully loaded, right?

Comment: If you have jQuery loaded, why not using jQuery?

Comment: FYI, if you add the function `scrollPrevious`, it works. Gives `1`. Just change `scrollPrevious` to `console.log`

Comment: Because I'm very new to web programming and I don't know how to do most things in javascript AND jQuery, just one or the other. On my page I have scrollNext and scrollPrevious functions defined. Could this be an issue with my host/server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to use jQuery like this:

```
  $(".arrow").on("click", function(event) {

      $(".slide").finish();

      if ( $(this).hasClass('right') ){

        scrollNext( $(this).data('cat') );

      } else {

        scrollPrevious( $(this).data('cat') );

      }

  });
```

Comment: No need of `for` to bind events here, just use `$('.arrow').on('click', function`. The click event will be bind on all the elements having `arrow` class.

Comment: Thank you for that,  the code definitely looks cleaner and more consistent. Any idea what could be causing this Uncaught TypeError though?

Comment: yea missed to remove the for loop, its unneccecary

Comment: looks like you're right: http://goo.gl/FTISFP

Weird that it was working a few months ago and isn't now. Now I just have to figure out a workaround :[

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you want to use plain javascript you can always do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dmn3z32j/2/

Comment: Oh man you are magnificent! Your example showed me that I could put `<svg cat="1">` instead of `<svg data-cat="1">` and change `this.dataset.cat` to `this.getAttribute("cat")` and it works just as intended. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome, sorry not to have said that from the start ))